# Exclude Search Links From Opening Using Beautiful Soup + Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, proxy, beautifulsoup

I'm running a script which googles a phrase, and then opens the links in a Chrome window. I want to exclude specific domain names from the search results being opened when I run the script.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction so I can add some code to the proper location to not have certain links be opened? Please see the code I'm using below right now.

```
import webbrowser
import sys
import pyperclip
import requests
import bs4


def start():
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    keyword = 'my+search+term'.join(sys.argv[1:])
else:
    # if no keyword is entered, the script would 
    # search for the keyword copied in the clipboard
    keyword = pyperclip.paste()

res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q='+keyword)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
links = soup.select('.r a')
tab_counts = min(5, len(links))

for i in range(tab_counts):
    webbrowser.open('https://google.com' + links[i].get('href'))


start()
```

Comment: You need to specify the domain names you want to exclude, i cant see that from your code. You can have a list of domain names you wish to exclude and then remove them from the links before opening the pages. you can as well use regular expression. so be a little more clare about what you want to do

Comment: I would like to create a list of the domian names that I wish to exclude. Do you know any pages or resources where I can look up how to add that to the above script? I think RegEx is a little over kill for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but wouldn't everything that you don't search for be excluded?  Try this and see if you can adapt it to your specific needs.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import webbrowser

text = 'hello world'
text = urllib.parse.quote_plus(text)

url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + text

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
for g in soup.find_all(class_='g'):
    print(g.text)
    print('-----')
```